# Run SSH command in .yml file

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci-runner

I am developing gitlab ci for test automation and deploy automation.
Test automation is complete. Now I want to complete deploy automation.

I can login to EC2 machine using *ssh -i test.pem 123.345.123.113* from terminal.

How can put `ssh -i test.pem 123.345.123.113` in .yml file?

Comment: You cannot run a command in a YAML file. You can put a command in a YAML file, on its own, (i.e. top-level scalar) or as a sequence element or mapping value (key is possible was well, but less often used).

Comment: So how can I login to ec2 machine?

Comment: Put the command in a scalar, either at the top-level, or as a sequence element, or as a mapping value. What have you tried? If it didn't work, what error did you get? Please do not comment, but edit your post to improve it.

Comment: */bin/sh: eval: line 44: ssh: not found.*   this error

Comment: What part of "Please do not comment, but edit your post to improve it" did you not understand? It would be good if you read the [tour] before any further posting on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly run a command through ssh like that:

```
ssh user1@server 'command'
```

Comment: SSH command is working from linux terminal. But I need run SSH command from .yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.
Ref:https://farhan-tanvir.medium.com/ci-cd-from-github-to-aws-ec2-using-github-action-e18b621c0507

```
name: CI/CD push app

on:
  push:
    branches: [ uat ]

    jobs:
      Deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2 
          - name: Deploy in EC2
            env:
                PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_PRIVATE_KEY_UAT  }}
                HOSTNAME : ${{ secrets.HOSTNAME_UAT  }}
                USER_NAME : ${{ secrets.USER_NAME_UAT  }}
                
            run: |
              echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key && chmod 600 private_key
              ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_key ${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME} 'ls'
```